# javascript: How to print values from several buttons into one single text field (one value after the other)?

Tags: javascript

I´m testing some javascript, and I want to print numbers into an input text type.
I have three buttons, each one with a number in it.
So far, the numbers are being printed every time I click on each. But if I print two buttons, or one button, twice, the first number is replaced.
**I would like to print every number into the same text field. One after the other.**

This is my form:

```
<input type="text" name="resultado" id="resultado"/>
<input id="1" name="1" onClick="uno();" type="button" value="1"/> 
<input id="2" name="2" onClick="dos();" type="button" value="2"/> 
<input id="3" name="3" onClick="tres();" type="button" value="3"/>
...
```

And this is my javascript:

```
function uno() {
    n1=document.getElementById('1').value;
    document.getElementById('resultado').value=n1;
}
function dos() {
    n2=document.getElementById('2').value;
    document.getElementById('resultado').value=n2;
}
function tres() {
    n3=document.getElementById('3').value;
    document.getElementById('resultado').value=n3;
```

How do I achieve that? **Besides, I know that there should be a better way to print out this without the need of one function for every button?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @meagar said, use the `+=` operator instead of `=`. But about the "better way to print out this without the need of one function for every button": use arguments to functions like this:

```
function appendToField(number){
    document.getElementById('resultado').value+=number;
}
```

and html:

```
<input type="text" name="resultado" id="resultado"/>
<input id="1" name="1" onClick="appendToField(1);" type="button" value="1"/> 
<input id="2" name="2" onClick="appendToField(2);" type="button" value="2"/> 
<input id="3" name="3" onClick="appendToField(3);" type="button" value="3"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `=`, which assigns a new value over the old value, try `+=`, which appends a value to the existing value.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
<input type="text" name="resultado" id="resultado"/>
<input id="1" name="1" onClick="document.getElementById('resultado').value+=this.id" type="button" value="1"/> 
<input id="2" name="2" onClick="document.getElementById('resultado').value+=this.id" type="button" value="2"/> 
<input id="3" name="3" onClick="document.getElementById('resultado').value+=this.id" type="button" value="3"/>
```

Or if you are using any server-side language, assuming it to be `php` then you can simplify it further it using `for` loop:

```
<input type="text" name="resultado" id="resultado"/>
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){
?>
<input id="<?php echo $i;?>" name="<?php echo $i;?>"  onClick="document.getElementById('resultado').value+=this.id" type="button" value="<?php echo $i;?>"/> 
<?php
}
?>
```